# phpexcel - Making file to download rather than saving in the server

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

Here is my Code to Inserting image to Excel,

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
 die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Jobin Jose");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Jobin Jose");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHPExcel classes.");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(o);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H(idea)(worry)') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
// Echo done
echo date('H(idea)(worry)') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
```

But it will just

```
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

Just rename the file of the php file to .xlxs file and store in the file path of the .php file , But How can i make the file to download once it is executed.

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

The above code is different code for file download of excel file.

How can i do this for my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have this in your code.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

in addition to the code your provided for the file download.

**You your code will be**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Jobin Jose");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy("Jobin Jose");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document");
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHPExcel classes.");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D2', 'world!');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg');
// Add a drawing to the worksheetecho date('H:i:s') . " Add a drawing to the worksheet\n";
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(150);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('C1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```